# How to bind jquery events in my view

Tags: ember.js

I'd like to use some third party libraries that are based on jquery with ember. This library
binds event on element like this :

```
$('#an-id')
    .bind('anEvent', function (event, params) { ... })
```

How do I catch the event enEvent into my Ember View and use an Ember based event handler. Something like :

```
App.MyView = Em.View.create({

   myEventHandler: function(event,params) { ....}
})
```

Answer (score 15):

Use the `didInsertElement` callback on a view, which gets invoked when the views has been added to the DOM. You can then access the added element via `this.$()`.

```
App.MyView = Em.View.create({
    didInsertElement: function() {
        this.$().bind('anEvent', ...);
    }
});
​
```

Comment: I recently posted a blog post (updated from an old post by wycats) that covers this and more integration with jQuery UI: http://www.lukemelia.com/blog/archives/2012/03/10/using-ember-js-with-jquery-ui/

Comment: In the 0.9.6 version we have the new Ember.evented mixing that can do the same thing.

Comment: I tried to use _$().bind(…_ but _this_ is bound to the DOM-Element than instead to the view object which is usually not desired.