# using custom jquery-events in ember.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

*I'm using a custom jQuery UI Plugin in my ember.js app, and would like to react on a custom jQuery event in order to update values of the controller/model.*

What I found: A [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9735349/how-to-bind-jquery-events-in-my-view) asked for the same purpose here on stackoverflow gives as answer to use jQuery.bind()/[jQuery.on() in the the *didInsertElement*-function of the view. The use of *jQuery.on()* in the *didInsertElement*-Method of the view causes the problem that *this* inside the event Handler is bound to the Dom-Element it occurred on.

So ideally there would be a way to get other jQuery events to work like the ones that ember brings with it: Calling the matching method names on the Ember.View- Instance.

Do you know any way to get custom jQuery events to work? Possibly using an Mixin for creating the appropriate methods on the view or the like?

Comment: The jQuery UI integration by Luke and Yehuda (http://www.lukemelia.com/blog/archives/2012/03/10/using-ember-js-with-jquery-ui/) btw. seems to only work with the build in jQUI widgets but _not_ with custom ones created by the jQueryUI widget factory helper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like this is a Javascript issue, not a jQuery or Ember issue. Understanding and manipulating what "this" is bound to is one of the biggest learning curves in Javascript:

```
///...in the view
didInsertElement : function(){
    var view = this;
    this.$().zoomablebg(); //this is the name of the custom jQ UI-Plugin
    // the view variable now holds a reference to the ember view
    // and creates a closure so that you can refer to it in the event handler
    this.$().on("zoomablebgstopdrag", function(e){ view.zoomablebgstopdrag(e) });
},
zoomablebgstopdrag: function(b){
    console.log(this); //this refers to the view now. 
},
//more view code
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hmm, thanks. But the trouble is, this brings us further down in the field of jQuery/Javascript event problems. It fixes a problem while creating another: you can't unregister the function from on(), since it was created anonymously.

Comment: ...but as I see now, the method to call a function on an ember view used in your jQueryUI integration (http://www.lukemelia.com/blog/archives/2012/03/10/using-ember-js-with-jquery-ui/) can be used on any jQueryUI object created by the jQuery Widget factory. So I may just use this to trigger some function on the view.

Comment: I know this is a bit old but I think it's still true : When you register an event listener like that in the `didInsertElement`, don't you have also to remove it in the onDestroy ?

Comment: @Sephy yes, it should be removed in `willDestroyElement`